# Why do certain text elements display smaller on iOS?

Tags: ios, fonts

On iOS devices, certain text elements are much smaller than they should be. It appears to only affect iOS devices and, if I'm not mistaken, a specific font.

I've tried setting the `-WebKit-text-size-adjust` to `none` and `100%`, and setting the font size on each element, both without success. I've scoured the web for other solutions and haven't found anything.

In the examples below, the text I'm referring to is the search field placeholder and the two dropdowns. Is there a way to get these text elements to display the same on iOS as they do on a desktop or Android devices?

[Incorrect font size on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQqST.jpg)

[Correct font size on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlurp.png)

Comment: They look the same to me. If anything the Android one looks smaller! Can you specify which are the too-small elements? Have you used the Web Debugger to understand what's going on?

Comment: These seem substantially different font weights. I would start by simplifying this down to a single element with a single CSS style that demonstrates the issue. With that, you should be able to post a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It is very hard to know what you've done from a screenshot of the final result. (In my experience, the creation of that MCVE often solves the problem for you…)